# ambiguity in G729 Annexes

Tags: sip, voip, sdp

In SIP SDP:

How to detect G729A codec by reading SDP media attributes ?
For example below SDP, says this is a **G729B** codec,

```
m = audio 33712 RTP/AVP 18 101
a = rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a = fmtp:18 annexb=yes
a = rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a = fmtp:101 0-15
```

If I get "annexb=no", does it mean **G729a** ?? or when I get "annexa=yes" only then its **G729a**. according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.729) G729 codec has various annexes like A, B, C, D, E, F etc... If I want to detect each of them can I depend on string "annex", for example I want to detect **G729F**, Can I depend on attribute string "annexf=yes" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC4856](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4856.html) Section 2.1.9

```
    annexb: indicates that Annex B, voice activity detection, is
    used or preferred.  Permissible values are "yes" and "no"
    (without the quotes); "yes" is implied if this parameter is
    omitted.
```

More details can be found From [RFC3551](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551#section-4.5.6) Section 4.5.6 (G.729, G.729a and G.729b) and 4.5.7 (G.729d and G.729e)

In general, G.729/G.729a/G.729b have the same format (with G.729b adding additional frames carrying the confort noise).

G.729 Annex C:

> This annex provides a description of an alternative implementation in floating-point arithmetic for the full version of ITU-T G.729 and Annex A.

G.729d and G.279e define different frame formats (and are identified differently in the SDP media line)

G.729 Annex F:

> This annex provides a description of integrating Annexes B and D, hereby defining DTX
> functionality for Annex D

G.729 Annex G:

> This annex provides a description of integrating Annexes B and E, hereby defining DTX
> functionality for Annex E.

So G.729f and G.729g do not introduce new formats, but use the frame formats from G.729d and G.279e: (on RF3551:)

> The voice activity detector (VAD) and comfort noise generator (CNG)
> algorithm specified in Annex B of G.729 may be used with Annex D and
> Annex E frames in addition to G.729 and G.729 Annex A frames.  The
> algorithm details for the operation of Annexes D and E with the Annex
> B CNG are specified in G.729 Annexes F and G.  Note that Annexes F
> and G do not introduce any new encodings.  Receivers MUST accept
> comfort noise frames if restriction of their use has not been
> signaled.  The MIME registrations for G729D and G729E in RFC 3555 [7]
> specify a parameter that MAY be used with MIME or SDP to restrict the
> use of comfort noise frames

The parameter mentioned above is the annexb=yes|no

---

In terms of representation in the SDP payload.

- G729, G729a (and G729c):

  - number in m= line: 18
  - a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
  - a=fmtp:18 annexb=no (or not present)
- G729b

  - number in m= line: 18
  - a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
  - a=fmtp:18 annexb=yes
- G729d

  - number in m= line: *n* (dynamic)
  - a=rtpmap:*n* G729D/8000
  - a=fmtp:*n* annexb=no (or not present)
- G729e

  - number in m= line: *n* (dynamic)
  - a=rtpmap:*n* G729E/8000
  - a=fmtp:*n* annexb=no (or not present)
- G729f

  - number in m= line: *n* (dynamic)
  - a=rtpmap:*n* G729D/8000
  - a=fmtp:*n* annexb=yes
- G729g

  - number in m= line: *n* (dynamic)
  - a=rtpmap:*n* G729E/8000
  - a=fmtp:*n* annexb=yes

Comment: thnx for the answer mr. jsantander.

Comment: Hi @JohnG, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Comment: thnx for the answer mr. jsantander. You mean when we get in SDP 'annexa=no' or 'annexb=yes' it means that its G729B, When we get 'annexb=no' or 'annexa=yes' means its G729A. all the other annexes (C,D,E,F,G,H,I,C+,J) can be detected from SIP SDP other attributes.

Comment: @JohnG Actually, no. There's no annexa parameter. The presence of the annexb=yes parameter indicates the support for the comfort noise generator. This distinguishes between AnnexA/AnnexB, but also between AnnexD/AnnexF and AnnexE/AnnexG. AnnexA/B is RTP code 18 (fixed) while AnnexD/AnnexF, AnnexE/AnnexG are dynamically assigned RTPs and indicated (I believe) with parameters a=rtpmap nn G729D/8000 or a=rtpmap nn G729E/8000 where nn is the dynamically assigned RTP.

Comment: @JohnG: Expanded the answer with the SDP details.

Comment: tht was awesome, & very very useful to me. thnx a lot JSANTANDER

Comment: @ jsantander: The annexa=yes/no applicable to G723 and not to G729 ??

Comment: @JohnG check RFC 4856, G723 does have an annexa parameter, indicates voice activity detection support.... it is a different AnnexA than the G729 Annex A :D

Comment: @jsantander When annexb is not specified, annexb=yes is implied. So in the G729/G729a case annexb=no *must* be specified and in G729b case annexb=yes may be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a misunderstanding in the above description of SDP's

From RFC7261

> When the offer or answer has G729 and the annexb parameter is absent,
> the offerer or answerer knows that it has implied the default
> "annexb=yes".  This is because the annexb attribute is part of the
> original registration of audio/G729 [RFC4856].

This clearly states that the absence of annexb is to be considered as annexb=yes